# Cache jQuery AJAX JSON response through global variables

Tags: jquery, ajax, caching

I have a screen design wherein i need to cache AJAX JSON response, so that i can use the same data for further requests. The screen design shows the historical data of payment, wherein the user can manipulate the date range. So, the initial call fetches me back the entire data for the past 10 years. And later when the user modifies the date range, i want the processing to occur through the cached data.

I am not planning to use client storage as they are not quite secure. Instead i wanted to check whether i can use global variables to store the JSON response after the first call and then for the later successive calls, i can get the data from the global variable rather than another server call.

```
//check whether the global variable is null or not
if($pymntHistData == null)
  {
  $.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    dataType: 'JSON',
                    url: 'PaymentHistory/_PaymentHistoryPartial',
                    data: {
                        fromDate: fromDate,
                        toDate: toDate
                    },
                    success: function(data) {
                     //store the response data in a global variable
                     $pymntHistData = data;
                    }
   }
```

Using global variables for caching is recommended as one of the alternatives for caching?Or are there any concerns with this approach?

Comment: Of course you can do this. However, I wouldn't use global variables, but hide the fetching logic behind an API that returns a promise. This makes your  code more flexible. More info: http://learn.jquery.com/code-organization/deferreds/

Comment: @FelixKling Arent deferreds usually used when some request take long time to proceed and apart from blocking it entirely, we send some request. I am wondering how deferreds actually fits in to hide the fetching logic.

Comment: I added an example as answer. It doesn't matter how long a request takes, promises are a way of *structuring* your code. Whether you are doing an asynchronous function call or a synchronous function call in the back doesn't matter. Promises let you abstract from the actual implementation.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that, but a better approach would be to use promises and hide the data fetching behind a function. That function can then take care of the caching

Imagine put your Ajax call in the function `getData`, which returns a promise:

```
var getData = function() {
    return $.ajax(...);
};
```

You can then call the function with

```
getData().then(function(data) { 
    /* do something with data */
});
```

and the callback is completely unaware of whether the data was actually fetched from the server, or from somewhere else.

So now we can change the implementation of `getData` without affecting the caller and implement caching:

```
var getData = (function() {
    var cache;

    return function() {
        if (cache) {
            return (new $.Deferred()).resolve(cache).promise();
        }
        return $.ajax(...).then(function(response) {
            cache = response;
        });
    };
}());
```